# Handling **kwargs in python as instance variables

Tags: python, oop, keyword-argument

I'm trying to finish a freeCodeCamp project with python, this is the link for the full description of the project

[Probability Calculator](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/scientific-computing-with-python/scientific-computing-with-python-projects/probability-calculator)

I’m not sure how to deal with the parameters they provide me
`hat = prob_calculator.Hat(blue=4, red=2, green=6)` because they’re not strings and I can’t use the split method.

Here’s what I’ve tried

```
class Hat:

def __nit__(**kwargs):
  content = []
  for key, value in kwargs.items():
    content.append(key)
```

I keep getting this "TypeError: Hat() takes no arguments" message

> Blockquote

Comment: 1) init, not just "nit"
2) `self` always comes as the first argument

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of your code? Also, it would be helpful if you placed the description of the task (or the relevant parts of it) into the original question. Links become invalid over time.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the feedback, I did some research and this is how it's done

```
class Hat:

  def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    content = []
    for key in kwargs.items():
        content.append(key)
```